# How to use Induction properly?

Tags: induction

I would like to prove the following equation using induction. However that seems somehow impossible at least for me:

$\sum\limits_{k=1}^{2n} {(-1)^k \cdot k^2}=(2n+1)\cdot n$

I tried to show that some property $E()$ holds for $n=1$, $E(1)$ but I just get something which doesnt makes sense:

$(-1)^1 \cdot 1^2=(2 \cdot 1+1) \cdot 1$

$-1=3$

Comment: Minor quibble: you don't solve an equation using induction, you prove an equality.

Comment: If you try for $n=0$, instead, the summation at the left hand side is empty, so it means $0$; the right hand side is $0$ as well.

Comment: I thought because of $k=1$ I have to begin with $n=1$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When $n=1$, the sum on the left hand side is from $k=1$ to $k=2$, which is

$$(-1)^1 \cdot 1^2 + (-1)^2 \cdot 2^2 = (-1) + 4 = 3$$

Comment: is it because of the $2n$ on the sum?

Comment: Exactly. The number of terms in the sum is $2n$.